# weird problem..the exact xml work in one host and not working in another

Tags: php, xml

i search alot for this but can't find an aswer...
I have made a working xml parser using php.
till today i host my files on a free web host, and everything works just fine.
today i got access to my college server and i host my files there.

now for some reason.. i can't make the parser work as i was in the free host...

**look on those files please:**
working site:

xml file:
[http://ofear.onlinewebshop.net/asce/calendar.xml]

working parser is this: [http://ofear.onlinewebshop.net/asce/calendar.php]

(the lower table is the xml,it's hebrew)

**not working site:**

xml file: [http://apps.sce.ac.il/agoda/calendar.xml]

not working parser is this: [http://apps.sce.ac.il/agoda/calendar.php]

anyone have idea why it's not working.. those are the same files and they should work.

**maybe it a server problem?**

calendar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<events>
    <record>
        <event>ערב פתוח לקורס מורי דרך</event>
        <eventDate>30/12/2010</eventDate>
        <desc>בשלוחת תל אביב</desc>
    </record>
        <record>
        <event>כנס חיפה לתיירות - 2 : נכנס יין יצאה תיירות</event>
        <eventDate>22/12/2010</eventDate>
        <desc>המרכז לחקר התיירות בשיתוף בית הספר לתיירות בישראל שמחים להודיע על כנס חיפה לתיירות 2 שיתקיים בחיפה בתאריכים 22-23 בדצמבר 2010. השנה יוקדש הכנס לנושא "תיירות היין"</desc>
    </record>
        <record>
        <event>פתיחת קורס מפעילי תיירות - תל אביב</event>
        <eventDate>5/12/2010</eventDate>
        <desc>ימי ראשון 17:30-20:45</desc>
    </record>
</events>
```

parser:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'calendar.xml' );

$events = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "record" );
foreach( $events as $record )
{
  $events = $record->getElementsByTagName( "event" );
  $event = $events->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $eventDates= $record->getElementsByTagName( "eventDate" );
  $eventDate= $eventDates->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $descs = $record->getElementsByTagName( "desc" );
  $desc = $descs->item(0)->nodeValue;

  echo "<tr><td>$event</td><td>$eventDate</td><td>$desc</td></tr>";
  }
?>
```

after a little debugging i saw that it's stop here:
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
and it's not doing anything after that. i think that the line above is the cos

Comment: Do you really expect us to help diagnose a parser whose source code we don't have access to?

Comment: What do you mean 'not working' ?

Comment: The parser is working. just not on this server.

Comment: i just added the xml and the parser. please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.This is the answer.
it's seems that the DOM function is not working on this server.
so i can't use this script.
I used this:

```
<?php
if (function_exists('domxml_new_doc')) {
    echo "DOM XML functions are available.<br />\n";
} else {
    echo "DOM XML functions are not available.<br />\n";
}
?>
```

and it's says that "DOM XML functions are not available"
so i need to see what can i do..

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you are checking the version of php being run on the server, if it's PHP 4 then you must use DOM XML.

And if it's PHP 5 be sure to check if the DOM Extension is installed.

Comment: ohh..can you refer me to some help about this issue?

Comment: is the $doc->load( 'calendar.xml' ) returning true? if it does, $doc->getElementsByTagName( "record" ) returns anything?

Comment: how can i know if it returning true.?, i think that in the windows host it's show the xml and in the unix is not.

Comment: maybe is something about this DOMDocument?

Comment: here http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php it says that DOM extension only works in PHP 5(if this is the case, is the extension installed?) for PHP 4 you should use DOM XML.

Comment: @Ofear: Do you understand the concept of "debugging?"  Because this is a perfect time to learn.  (1) Locate the likely spot of the bug -- in this case, the `$doc->load()` call. (2) `echo` the state of some variables around this location. (3) Run the script. (4) If you find a problem, fix it.  (5) Repeat from step 1 until there are no more problems.

Comment: ok so.. i did alittle debugging.. and it's not doing this line at all..$doc = new DOMDocument();  it's just stop there